# python import the imports of parent

Tags: python, import

Is it somehow possible to import all of the imports of the parent script automatically?

Comment: Erm... what? I don't understand what you're asking, or what you're trying to do. Do you have something that is not working?

Comment: I want all child objects to assume the imports of the parent

Comment: Code tends to be concerned with imports (functions that it can call from other modules), where as "objects" are just data. What you're asking still doesn't make sense. Do you have an example of what you're trying to do that isn't working?

Comment: @kamik423 I feel that whatever you **are trying** to do here there is likely a better solution. Please consider asking a more concrete question. This question as it is is likely to not yield you any answer ryou're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you do know that when you import it does not re-import if it has already been imported in a different module, as such there is no computational overhead to re-import modules you will be using... it tends to be bad practice to implicitly handle imports (such as what you are asking)

eg. `from other_module import *`  is bad practice ... it is much better to just re-import the things you will be using

I cannot imagine any valid use case where the behavior you are asking about would be the best (or really even an acceptable) solution